# Cannot find name 'cordova'. ionic build ios

Tags: ionic2, ngcordova

I am using ionic2 build .
I did `ionic plugin add  cordova-plugin-file` and used following code.

```
import {File} from 'ionic-native';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalVars {
  constructor(platform:Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.appRootFolder = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
    }
  }
}
```

then I did   `ionic build android`  and I got this error

> Cannot find name 'cordova'

After  2 hour of struggling , I resolved the issues by following commands

```
npm install -g typings
typings install dt~cordova --save --global 
typings install dt~cordova/plugins/filesystem --save  --global
```

This helped in building android , but still fails for iOS.   when I run this `ionic build ios` I still get

> Cannot find name 'cordova'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote this line(**declare var cordova:any;**) at the top of file

```
import {File} from 'ionic-native';
declare var cordova:any;
```

And the problem is solved for me.

Answer (score 2):

As of lately, you can do this:

In CLI, from your project folder:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

Then, in your component/class file:

```
import { File } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova: any;
const fs:string = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
File.checkDir(this.fs, 'mydir')
    .then(_ => console.log('yay'))
    .catch(err => console.log('boooh'));
```

Many native plugins are now well implemented and documented by the Ionic Team :)

Source: [Ionic Native docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/)

Answer (score 0):

Try copying `cordova.d.ts` file and plugins folder from here - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/cordova230

And paste this folder and file in your `project/typings` directory.